# 16.04LTS 64bit sees only 3.9GB of memory out of 8GB

Tags: ram

`free -m output`:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3951        1291        1720          41         939        2362
Swap:          4094           0        4094
```

`dmidecode` output:

```
Handle 0x000C, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 8 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 2
Handle 0x000D, DMI type 19, 15 bytes
Memory Array Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x0012FFFFFFF
    Range Size: 4864 MB
    Physical Array Handle: 0x000C
    Partition Width: 1
Handle 0x000E, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000C
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK0
    Type: Other
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 533 MHz
    Manufacturer: Corsair       
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: AssetTagNum0
    Part Number: CMV4GX3M1A1333C9  
    Rank: Unknown
Handle 0x000F, DMI type 20, 19 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x000FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 4 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x000E
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x000D
    Partition Row Position: 1
Handle 0x0010, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000C
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK1
    Type: Other
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 533 MHz
    Manufacturer: Corsair       
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: AssetTagNum1
    Part Number: CMV4GX3M1A1333C9  
    Rank: Unknown
Handle 0x0011, DMI type 20, 19 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00100000000
    Ending Address: 0x001FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 4 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x0010
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x000D
    Partition Row Position: 1
```

Answer (score 4):

The system detects both 4096MB RAM bricks (your 8GB in total) correctly and they seem to work well. I am sure your problem is still hardware related though.

We see that the 8GB of RAM are detected, but only a bit less than 4GB are usable. There are not enough memory addresses to which your RAM could be mapped though. All the remaining memory which can not get mapped to an address can not be used.

Your machine obviously can only map 4GB because any of the responsible components is limited to 32 bit addresses. The really usable amount of RAM is a bit smaller because e.g. your graphics card's video memory also needs to get mapped into the same address range.

You are running 64 bit Ubuntu, so neither the OS nor the CPU can be the problem. I am sure the component which annoys us here is your chipset (also known as North Bridge) that only supports an address width of 32 bit and therefore limits the address range to only 4 GB.

You can verify the address width of your chipset using this command:

```
sudo lshw | grep -m1 width
```

A result of `width: 32 bits` proves me right and explains your issues.

Unfortunately there is no software solution, the only thing you can do is to replace your chipset which means to get a complete new mainboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got an older motherboard, it may not support more than 4GB max (2x2GB), and inserting 8GB (2x4GB) could give you the result you're seeing. Go to the manufacturer’s web set and look up the specs for your board, and see if there's that limit on memory size.

I'm assuming that you only have 2 physical slots for memory. If that's not the case, then you've probably just got the memory inserted in the wrong slots to interleave memory correctly. If you've got 4 physicals slots for memory, and they're color-coded black and white, insert the memory into similar colored physical memory slots.

Also, if you do get 8GB to work, you'll want to increase your swap file size to 1-1.5 times physical memory.

You can also try and boot a Ubuntu Live CD, and see if the same problem exists. That would eliminate some strange software problem.